# Distributed File System Hotfixes

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dfs-r

Quick question. I've been doing some research on Windows Server DFS replication and ran across this article about hot fixes for DFS and DFSR (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968429/en-us) I'm wondering if anyone knows if these hot fixes have been included in any other type of service pack or other update (or if they would have been installed via Windows Update)? Clicking through to the KB article for the update doesn't seem to give any indication.

We're running Windows 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will read a little more deeply into that page, it actually tells you. For example, for Win2k8 R2, KB article 975763 states, under the column "Hotfix type and availability" :

> To install this hotfix, you must have Windows Server 2008 R2
>   installed. This hotfix is available for individual download and is
>   included in Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1.

So there you go. For that one, it tells you that it's included in a later SP. For any that don't, they aren't.